# Is there a way to base Susy gutter widths off a percentage of the container width?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-sass, susy

On reading the documentation Susy takes its gutter width as a percentage of the column width.

**I have a container that has a width of 768px**

**I have 3 columns**

**I want each gutter to be 5% of 768px which is 38.4px**

**I am using a gutter-position of split**

Doing the following fives me a gutter width of 3.33333%:

```
+with-layout(3 38.4px)
  .three-col
    +span(3 of 3)
```

But doing this gives me the correct gutter width of 5%:

```
+with-layout(3 0.428572)
  .three-col
    +span(3 of 3)
```

I found this number out by trial and error and cannot seem to work out the work out the formula.

I assume there is a relationship between the following:

**Number of columns: 3**

**Number of gutters: 6**

**Desired percentage gutter of container: 5%**

**Number I need to supply Susy to get my desired gutter percentage (of container): 0.428572**

How do I get I set Susy gutter widths based on a percentage of my container width?

Answer (score 0):

I made a function in Sass that converts a percentage of a container to a gutter value that is usable by Susy. **I am assuming a split gutter here**, so there is half a gutter on each side of a column.

Maybe this will help someone else!

```
//Convert a percentage of the container to a susy gutter width
//This function assumes a split gutter position
@function calculate-susy-gutter($containerWidth, $numCols, $percentage-of-container: 0.05)
  //get the number of gutters
  $numGutters: $numCols * 2
  //work out the target gutter width based on the container
  $singleGutterWidth: $containerWidth * $percentage-of-container
  //work out the width of all the gutters
  $totalGutterWidth: $singleGutterWidth * $numGutters
  //work out the width of all the columns
  $totalColumnWidth: $containerWidth - $totalGutterWidth
  //work out the width of one column
  $singleColumnWidth: $totalColumnWidth/$numCols
  //work out the percentage that single gutter is of a column
  $gutterPercentageOfColumn: $singleGutterWidth/$singleColumnWidth
  //multiply the value by two
  //Using the split gutter position Susy sees the gutter on each side as half a gutter
  //so we need to double it
  //Therefore the original percentage of the container accounted for one half gutter
  @return $gutterPercentageOfColumn * 2
```